# Unable to parse to jodatime

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I am trying to parse my JSON string into a Joda (DateTime) object.

The following is my code.

```
Data.log("Time in json: " + json.getString("delivery_by"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
this.deliveryBy = fmt.parseDateTime(json.getString("delivery_by"));
Data.log("Time found as: " + this.deliveryBy.toString());
```

The error is

```
Time in json: 2015-10-23T13:15:00+00:00
( 7406): exception
( 7406): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-10-23T13:15:00+00:00" is malformed at "+00:00"
```

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This method expects a format that includes milliseconds (note `SSS`):
   method : `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`
   format : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`
2. You appear to be passing a format without milliseconds so use this method:
   method : `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()`
   format : `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ`

The error message is a little bit misleading as it fails to parse the timezone for milliseconds

Comment: I landed up using "ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()". This worked for me.